# How can I make suction cups stay securely to a tiled shower wall?

Tags: bathroom, hanging

I am trying to hang a mirror in the shower and it simply will not stay on the wall. It does not weigh more than a couple of pounds. There are two suction cups.

Things I've tried:

- Cleaning the tile surface before attaching
- Using water on the suction cups
- Using soapy water on the suction cups

Comment: If someone could create and add the "suction-cup" tag for me I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is "glue" not an acceptable answer for some reason?

Comment: @BRPocock Unless you know of a non-permanent glue or adhesive it would not be acceptable. It's for a condo that will eventually be rented out so the mirror will be there only temporarily.

Comment: This may be obvious, but for completeness I wanted to mention: make sure you're not spanning more than one tile with the suction cup since the gap between the tiles will prevent them from maintaining suction.

Comment: @Johnny The OCD part of me never would have let that happen :)

Comment: I only mentioned it because a friend had a problem with her new shower caddy staying put, and it turns out that she had small 1" square tiles  that were smaller than the suction cup, so no  matter where she put  it, the  suction cup spanned  tiles.  We  replaced  her 2 large suction cups with 6  small  ones that could fit on a  single tile and then  it was fine.

Comment: I can't get mine to stick either.  And I don't span tiles.

Comment: When all else fails switch to Command Strips. They make them for the bathroom. Have some hooks in mine and I don't worry about them.

Comment: Is it a regular suction cup, or a [power lock suction cup](http://www.amazon.com/InterDesign-Power-Suction-Hooks-Combo/dp/B002OJC1J8)? The latter will provide a much better hold.

Answer (score 13):

You could definitely just silicone the suction cups to the tile.  This is kind of permanent in the sense that you will not be rearranging this, but not so permanent that you are hurting the tile.  To take it out a putty knife would do the trick.  Might have to use a solvent to get rid of the remnants but not a big job at all.

Comment: A very thin layer of RTV silicone caulk/sealant around the outer part of the suction cup is all it takes.  You might be okay with acrylic if that's what you have on hand. If it sticks to the cup and doesn't peel off, you're set.  All surfaces need to be very well cleaned first.  91% rubbing alcohol on a paper towel did a fine job for me.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem recently with a shower caddy from IKEA.  It lasted for about four months, then I bumped it, and I couldn't get it to stay.  I cleaned the tile and the suction cups without success.  The caddy fell in 15 minutes after putting it up.  I found that my problem was how I cleaned the suction cups.  After I washed them, I dried them with a cloth.  This left tiny fibers on the suction cup which affected the suction.  I then tried to let the cups air dry after cleaning them, and now they suck!

Try to clean your cups really well and let them air dry before using.

Comment: If fibers are the issue, would a microfiber cloth work as well?

Answer (score 11):

The best approach I have found is to make sure everything is clean and then apply a small layer of petroleum jelly to the suction cup.  It helps to create an air tight seal.

Comment: I've used a film of soap for the same purpose. Seems to help.

Answer (score 5):

a layer of leftover soap scum on the tile or suction cups could be preventing the suction cups from sticking. Cleaning with vinegar or an appropriate cleaner might help.

Suction cups stick best when damp. However some suction cups are poorly made and will never stick well no matter what you do. You may just need to replace the suction cups with higher quality ones. the kinds that have a hinge stick best in my experience.