# How can I mount a clock on tiles?

Tags: bathroom, tile, mounting

My father likes to have a clock in our bathroom. Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the clock is already damaged because we need to move it all the time when we want to open the window. I would like to mount it on the wall, but we have tiles there and cannot drill a hole there.

The clock has the usual "hole" to mount it on the wall with a nail:

[image]

I would like to have something like TESA powerstrips which holds very good, but with a knob on it so that we can easily put the clock on the wall and remove it if the battery runs out. How is something like that called?

Comment: English is not my mother tongue. Please correct my question if you find errors / unusual phrased sentences in it so that I can learn how to say it correctly.

Comment: [How can I make suction cups stay securely to a tiled shower wall?][1]

I've had them stick solidly to windows for *years*.

  [1]: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/38202/how-can-i-make-suction-cups-stay-securely-to-a-tiled-shower-wall

Comment: Are you not permitted to drill through the tile, or do you just not have a suitable drill bit?

Comment: @RowlandShaw The flat is rented. I am not permitted to drill through the tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find a suitable self stick hook of some sort that can hold up the clock. With proper pre-cleaning of the smooth tile surface I would expect a good brand of self stick to stay adhered for a long time.                                                                                                                                                                                     [image]

Some folks have suggested energizing the self stick glue on this type of product by painting on a layer of clear nail polish varnish before before sticking it up to the wall. If you do this make sure to let it dry well before using the hook to hold up the clock.

Note that if the hook style is a bit to long to accomodate the mounting feature on the back of the clock it is easy to cut off part of the hook tip.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation.  I used velcro mounting pads.  They come in different shapes and sizes.  You can cut them to fit. They will allow you to remove the clock when the battery needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Well first you need to create a sealed backing for the clock or it will rust out in a month.  So some plastic and caulk.  Then you can basically use whatever you want to mount it - glue, silicone, velcro, double sided tape, suction cups....